# GraphQL angular apollo-client. Read from cache throw error but the same query to the server works fine

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to request data from the cache which is already there. I've checked with the usage of Apollo Chrome plugin.

```
      const inCache = this.apollo.getClient().readQuery({
        query: gql`
          query {
            foo(id: "foo0") {
              id
              bar {
                id
              }
            }
          }
        `
      });
```

The error looks like this:

```
MyHtml.html:20 ERROR Invariant Violation: Can't find field id on object {
  "barSubResourses": [
    {
      "type": "id",
      "generated": false,
      "id": "SubResourse:subResourse3",
      "typename": "SubResourse"
    },
    {
      "type": "id",
      "generated": false,
      "id": "SubResourse:subResourse2",
      "typename": "SubResourse"
    }
  ],
  "__typename": "Bar"
}.
```

reading from cache works fine if I don't include sub resoures
Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found the source of the issue. There was a query without id for `Bar` among my queries. I've double-checked that chrome plugin still has id data for the bars. It looks like a mismatch.
Anyway, it seems like there is a rule of thumb to ask `id` for every entity in each query.